# Java Extract Wikipedia Info

Tags: java, html, jsoup, screen-scraping

I'm new using **Jsoup** could you help me to extract info from this wikipedia page to have only Starring Names ? The structure of the page (summarize) is this one:

```
<table class="infobox vevent" style="width:22em;font-size:90%;"><tbody><tr><th colspan="2" class="summary" style="text-align:center;font-size:125%;font-weight:bold;font-size:110%;font-style:italic;">Pulp Fiction</th></tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><a href="/wiki/File:Pulp_Fiction_(1994)_poster.jpg" class="image"><img alt="Pulp Fiction (1994) poster.jpg" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3b/Pulp_Fiction_%281994%29_poster.jpg" decoding="async" width="220" height="327" class="thumbborder" data-file-width="220" data-file-height="327" /></a><div style="font-size:95%;padding:0.35em 0.35em 0.25em;line-height:1.25em;">Theatrical release poster</div></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Directed by</th><td><a href="/wiki/Quentin_Tarantino" title="Quentin Tarantino">Quentin Tarantino</a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Produced by</th><td><a href="/wiki/Lawrence_Bender" title="Lawrence Bender">Lawrence Bender</a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Written by</th><td>Quentin Tarantino</td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Story by</th><td><div class="plainlist">
<ul><li>Quentin Tarantino</li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Roger_Avary" title="Roger Avary">Roger Avary</a></li></ul>
</div></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Starring</th><td><div class="plainlist">
<ul><li><a href="/wiki/John_Travolta" title="John Travolta">John Travolta</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Samuel_L._Jackson" title="Samuel L. Jackson">Samuel L. Jackson</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Uma_Thurman" title="Uma Thurman">Uma Thurman</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Harvey_Keitel" title="Harvey Keitel">Harvey Keitel</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Tim_Roth" title="Tim Roth">Tim Roth</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Amanda_Plummer" title="Amanda Plummer">Amanda Plummer</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Maria_de_Medeiros" title="Maria de Medeiros">Maria de Medeiros</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Ving_Rhames" title="Ving Rhames">Ving Rhames</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Eric_Stoltz" title="Eric Stoltz">Eric Stoltz</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Rosanna_Arquette" title="Rosanna Arquette">Rosanna Arquette</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Christopher_Walken" title="Christopher Walken">Christopher Walken</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Bruce_Willis" title="Bruce Willis">Bruce Willis</a></li></ul>
</div></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Cinematography</th><td><a href="/wiki/Andrzej_Seku%C5%82a" title="Andrzej Sekuła">Andrzej Sekuła</a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Edited by</th><td><a href="/wiki/Sally_Menke" title="Sally Menke">Sally Menke</a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;"><div style="padding:0.1em 0;line-height:1.2em;">Production<br />companies </div></th><td><div style="vertical-align:middle;"><div class="plainlist">
<ul><li><a href="/wiki/A_Band_Apart" title="A Band Apart">A Band Apart</a></li>
<li><a href="/wiki/Jersey_Films" class="mw-redirect" title="Jersey Films">Jersey Films</a></li></ul>
</div></div></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;">Distributed by</th><td><a href="/wiki/Miramax_Films" class="mw-redirect" title="Miramax Films">Miramax Films</a></td></tr><tr><th scope="row" style="white-space:nowrap;padding-right:0.65em;"><div style="padding:0.1em 0;line-height:1.2em;white-space:normal;">Release date</div></th><td><div class="plainlist">
<ul><li>May&#160;21,&#160;1994<span style="display:none">&#160;(<span class="bday dtstart published updated">1994-05-21</span>)</span>&#32;(<a href="/wiki/1994_Cannes_Film_Festival" title="1994 Cannes Film Festival">Cannes</a>)</li>
```

How can I exctract for instance John Travolta without extract Roger Avary ?

I tried in this way, but I 'm not able to put the **attributes** "Starring" and extract only them. In my code I have extracted all the text in the table, but I want just the characters identified by "Starring" attributes.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
final Document document = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulp_Fiction").get();
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Attore;integratedSecurity=true;";
for(Element row : document.select("table.infobox li a")) {

     String at = row.text();
     System.out.println(at);
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Try to remove the vevent css class from select method ` document.select("table.infobox th li a")`

Comment: Hi @basitraza, thanks but in this way we do not obtain what we want. We need to extract only the names in the part of table related to Starrings and not for example "Director". How we can specify an attributes for the part of table ?

Comment: In your sample html you can extract the `Starring` by using this selector `table.infobox div.plainlist li a`.

For the selector details visit the jsoup link https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: @basitraza however there are more than 1 with div.plainlist, what can I do ? I add more lines from wikipedia page.

Comment: try `table.infobox > div.plainlist li a`

Comment: @basitraza sorry it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
document.select("table.infobox tr:contains(Starring) div.plainlist li a")
```

Explanation:

```
table.infobox // select the table with the class name infobox
tr:contains(Starring)  // finds tr elements containing the text "Starring"
div.plainlist li a  // finally find in obove selected tr all a tags in a li tag inside the div with a class name plainlist
```